# Почему разделялась ветка в Git?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitkraken

Можете объяснить, что происходило с веткой dev на последних комитах, почему она разделялась

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что перед этими коммитами dev влили в prelife

Comment: У вас там слияние произошло, ветку dev объединили (merge) с prelife.